# How to include all Zend Classes at once in Core PHP project?

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am using Zend Framework classes in my CORE PHP project.
i am not using all features of ZF just need some classes.

i need to know How to include all Zend Classes at once so that i don't include it one by one each time i need it.

in ZF we are doing so

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
)));

public function _initRegisterLibraries(){
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); 
    return $moduleLoader;
  }
```

how can we achieve same in CORE PHP in which i want to use some zend classes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't Zend autoload its classes?

Comment: @Matt certainly Loader does that. How would i do that in core PHP project ??

Comment: Are you saying this isn't a Zend project?

Comment: yes this is not Zend Project i am using Zend Translation in it so i need to include ZF

Comment: Have you tried [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)?

Comment: Ohhhh i forgot this features i guess its in PHP5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I do this in any PHP File :

```
define('WWW_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..');

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(WWW_PATH . '/library'), get_include_path())));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$autoloader->registerNamespace('Zend_');
```

Then I can instantiate any Zend class I want, for exemple :

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysql();
```

(Just be sure the `WWW_PATH` point to were the library directory is currently in)